# On the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: can there be something in between?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For any couple of random variables $X$ and $Y$,
$$
\displaystyle |\mathbb{E} (XY)|^{2}\leq \mathbb{E} (X^{2})\mathbb{E} (Y^{2})
$$
Is it possible to put an intermediate bound, like
$$
\displaystyle |\mathbb{E} (XY)|^{2}\leq\color{red}{ \mathbb{E} (|X|)\mathbb{E} (Y^{2})}\leq \mathbb{E} (X^{2})\mathbb{E} (Y^{2})
$$
?

*Addendum after the answer given by @Prem*. What I'm really looking for is a bound of this form
$$
\mathbb{E}(XY)\leq \mathbb{E}[|X|]\bigg(\text{whatever that wouldn't contain } \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[|X|]}\bigg)
$$

Comment: If your intermediate bound held, then putting Y to a constant variable always 1 would lead to $|E(X)|^2 \le E(|X|) \le E(X^2)$ for all variables $X.$

Comment: Between "Cauchy-Schwarz" ? Answer : [Buniakovski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: ric, That's so but what about the middle term being between those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Question title says that you want "something" between the 2 terms , while the Body gives only some sort of Example term. [[ User "coffeemath" has already highlighted that this Example term will not work ]]

$$\displaystyle |\mathbb{E} (XY)|^{2} \leq [[\ \ ??\ \ ]] \leq \mathbb{E} (X^{2})\mathbb{E} (Y^{2})$$

Well , there are various ways we can go about that. I will give only 2 Examples.

**(1) Using Averaging :**

$$\displaystyle |\mathbb{E} (XY)|^{2} \leq [[\ \ (|\mathbb{E} (XY)|^{2} + \mathbb{E} (X^{2})\mathbb{E} (Y^{2}))/2\ \ ]] \leq \mathbb{E} (X^{2})\mathbb{E} (Y^{2})$$

Here , we are putting the Average between the 2 values , hence it will be true.

**(2) Using Expectation of Absolute value :**

$$\displaystyle |\mathbb{E} (XY)|^{2} \leq [[\ \ |\mathbb{E} (|XY|)|^{2}\ \ ]] \leq \mathbb{E} (X^{2})\mathbb{E} (Y^{2})$$

Here , we are converting $XY$ to $|XY|$ before taking Expectation , hence it will be between the other 2 terms.

There are other ways we can put "something" between the 2 terms.

Comment: Thanks. I gave in the body that specific example because I was looking for some bound of this form $\mathbb{E}[|X|](\text{whatever that wouldn't contain } 1/\mathbb{E}[|X|])$